# sts 3.6.4 crashes(not responding) on start-up, Windows 8.1, 64X

Tags: eclipse, windows, spring, zip, spring-tool-suite

Have now DL STS 3.6.4, 64x, a few times.  Have unzipped/extracted with 7 Zip, PeaZip, and the Windows OS's zip.  Windows zip didn't work at all. 7 & Pea would seem to have worked but when I try to run STS, it freezes, then 'not respondig'.  Suggestions?

**DL LOCAL:** https://spring.io/tools/sts/all

**Pic:** http://screencast.com/t/Sm8rLAbKm3

Comment: can you capture a thread dump (using jps and jstack) while STS is freezing? Maybe we can see from that dump that is causing the freeze. Thanks!!!

Comment: @MartinLippert I'll work on that.  I have a few new development.  Would you mind emailing me reedwilliams8404@gmail.com